# PHP How to query missing values between two numbers?

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i have mysql table which named numbers like this;

| ID | Number |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3002 |
| 2 | 3004 |
| 2000 | 7545 |

When i need to insert a new data products table i have to find first number which is not on this table between(3000 to 35000). I mean i need to find first number between this numbers not on numbers table. How can i find it?

```
$statement = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM numbers");
$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($result as $row)

{
    $arr1[] = $row['numbers'];

}
$arr2 = range(3000,35000);                                                    
$missing_numbers = array_diff($arr2,$arr1);
print_r($missing_numbers);
```

i tried array_diff but i gives results with different keys. When i write $missing_numbers[0] i want to see first missing number.

Comment: So, "3000", for this example?

Comment: So what first missing number should be? 3003?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the first missing number, it may be easier to read the rows in number order and check for the first one which isn't in the sequence you are after.  So a query (with the start and end points as parameters) order by the number and a counter which is what it's expecting to get on each row...

```
$startPoint = 3000;
$endPoint = 35000;
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT number
        FROM numbers
        WHERE number >= :start
            and number <= :end
        order by number");
$statement->execute([
        'start' => $startPoint,
        'end' => $endPoint
]);
$expected = $startPoint;
while ($row = $statement->fetch())  {
    if ( $row['number'] != $expected )  {
        echo "Missing=" . $expected;
        break;
    }
    $expected++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution will work only thing missing is reordering of the indexes which can be done by using the array_values() function. Update your last lines of code as -

```
$missing_numbers = array_values(array_diff($arr2,$arr1));
print_r($missing_numbers);
```

so on printing $missing_numbers[0] you should get the first missing number.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, just need reset keys after array_diff:

```
...
$missing_numbers = array_values(missing_numbers);
print_r($missing_numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you want do it only by using MySQL query and later get the result in PHP you need to do something like this :

Create temporray table with your example :

```
create table test123(id integer, Number varchar(100))
        #insert into test123 (ID, Number) values (1, '3002');
        #insert into test123 (ID, Number) values (2, '3004');
        #insert into test123 (ID, Number) values (2000, '7545');
```

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE WITH RANGE 3000 - 35000

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableTest AS (
        
SELECT @row := @row + 1 AS row FROM 
(select 0 union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t,
(select 0 union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t2, 
(select 0 union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t3, 
(select 0 union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t4, 
(select 0 union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t5,
(SELECT @row:=3000) numbers WHERE @row  < 35000

)
```

AND FINALLY you can just select numbers that's not inside your table with data

```
select * from tableTest t where t.row not in ( select Number from test123)
```

The output will be select all numbers as you wanted.
[image]